# Something.Text containing two strings

Tags: c#

I can choose multiple texts to `SelectedFileText` like

```
something\text.css

something\multiple.php
```

My code is

```
string NameParser = SelectedFileText.Text;
string[] words = NameParser.Split('\\');
string myLastWord = words[words.Length - 1];
```

And I can parse the text so it shows only **multiple.php**, but the problem is I need to get both lines out, not only the last one. So it work like this

**text.css**

**multiple.php**

Sorry for beeing bit unclear. I have already solved the problem how get the filename path.GetFilename.

The problem is SelectedText.text property contains two lines with full filename and directory, I just used NameParser to parse SelectedFileText.text where it inherits the text.

Comment: `Path.GetFileName(source)`?

Comment: So you have 2 lines of text you want to get the filename of? How are you receiving the 2 lines (or the collection of lines)?

Comment: There are helper functions for things like paths. Implementing *properly* working methods yourself might be a bit complicated.

Comment: will list or array of string work? as you will get multiple values in one variable then.

Comment: What is stopping you from processing both lines?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [Path.GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) e.g.

```
// Actually, myLastWord is a file name like "text.css" or "multiple.php"
string myLastWord = Path.GetFileName(SelectedFileText.Text);
```

If you want all the text, *except* the file name (i.e. *directory name*), `Path` class helps out again (via [Path.GetDirectoryName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
string dirName = Path.GetDirectoryName(SelectedFileText.Text);
```

**Edit**: if you have a *multiline text* (see comments below) and you have extract files' names you can try *Linq*:

```
 string[] fileNames = string
   .Split(SelectedFileText.Text, 
          new char[] { '\r', '\n'}, 
          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   .Select(line => Path.GetFileName(line))
   .ToArray();
```

Comment: and what about " I can parse the text so it shows only multiple.php, but the problem is I need to get both lines out, not only the last one" part of question ?

Comment: @Amit: `Path.GetFileName` to get the "last word" (file name) while `Path.GetDirectoryName` to obtain the "first words" (directory name) if I've understood you right

Comment: I think Op has two files in `something` directory, he has one file name in his `string` but he wants both file names at the end of his logic. as he stated his desired output too at the end of question

Answer (score 2):

If your SelectedText.Text property contains two (or more) lines of text consisting in a full filename and you want to retrieve just the file name of all lines you can work with

```
var parts = NameParser.Split(Environment.Newline)
                      .Select(x => Path.GetFilename(x));

foreach(string s in parts)
   Console.WriteLine(s);
```